# How to design tables when data can be divided into categories but all are belong to one common category?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

In my database I have tables called `patient` and `target_metrics`. The `target_metrics` table shows the metrics related to the patient.

The "metrics" are divided into 3 categories. They are,

1. glucose
2. measurements
3. activity

All of these are "belongs" to the patient.

So I divided these sections into separate tables, like below. In the below image, I have removed the field names for privacy reasons.

[image]

Anyway, I also do believe that it will be very easy for implementations if we remove the entire `target_metric` table and link all other tables directly to `patient`. All of these tables will contain a one record per one `patient`, forming a `one-to-one` relationship.

In your experience, what would be the advice? Keep it as in image or remove `target_metric` by linking the other tables to `patient`?

Comment: Are you sure that there can be only one metric of each kind for each patient?

Comment: I also created medical SW in the past but answer depends on details you need to store from examinations. Because different examinations produce different metrics and depends if for example a doctor would like to see graphs of glucose level over time etc. If so I recommend separate tables for every metric all interconnected with patient_id.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Sure. That is how it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loose the `target_metric` table. Also loose the extra `id` column:

```
target_metric_glucose table
---------------------------
patient_id
...
```

Where `patient_id` is foreign and primary key in the table.

Comment: I recommend to have unique ID for every row in every table for integrity. Patients will have more records for examinations over time. Diabetics will have tons of glucose metrics etc...

Comment: OP explicitly does say otherwise for his system. Due to the `last_update` column it looks like only the last entry is saved and no history.

Comment: We do not see other tables in whole - `last_update` can be part of every table - it can be standard audit column. Plus - imagine yourself to explain to the doctor that all older records are gone and only last one is available. :-)

Comment: @JosMac: Yes, `last_update` and `date_created` are in every table. They are audit columns and used for "date based" searches.